# Can't iterate correctly over specific files in folder with endings {*-enterprise.ipa,*.apk}

Tags: bash

I have a folder containing these app files:

```
mles:fairs-ionic mles$ ls build
build/com.solutions.enterprise.fairs.dev_v2.2.0.17_20170720_1423-enterprise.ipa
build/com.solutions.enterprise.fairs_v2.2.0.17_20170720_1423-enterprise.ipa
build/de.fairs.dev_v2.2.0.17_20170720_1423-enterprise.apk
build/de.fairs_v2.2.0.17_20170720_1423-appstore.ipa
build/de.fairs_v2.2.0.17_20170720_1423-enterprise.apk
```

I need to uppload all of them except the `*-appstore.ipa` one. More specifically these one:

```
mles:fairs-ionic mles$ ls build/{*-enterprise.ipa,*.apk}
build/com.solutions.enterprise.fairs.dev_v2.2.0.17_20170720_1423-enterprise.ipa
build/com.solutions.enterprise.fairs_v2.2.0.17_20170720_1423-enterprise.ipa
build/de.fairs.dev_v2.2.0.17_20170720_1423-enterprise.apk
build/de.fairs_v2.2.0.17_20170720_1423-enterprise.apk
```

In my bash script I've tried:

```
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
appFiles=($(cd ${DIR}/build;ls {*-enterprise.ipa,*.apk}))
echo ${appFiles};
echo "loop"
for appFile in "${appFiles[@]}"
do
  echo ${appfile}
  #app_upload "${appfile}"
done
```

this yields:

```
mles:fairs-ionic ben$ ./test.sh 
com.solutions.enterprise.fairs.dev_v2.2.0.17_20170720_1423-enterprise.ipa
loop
```

`appFiles` only contains one row, and the `appfile` variable in the loop is always empty.

How can I iterate over all the files in the build folder except the .ipa files with appstore in the filename (`build/de.fairs_v2.2.0.17_20170720_1423-appstore.ipa`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable `appfile` is not defined only `appFile`, So change

```
echo ${appfile}
```

to

```
echo ${appFile}
```

Edit the line displaying all the data

```
echo ${appFiles};
```

To

```
echo ${appFiles[*]};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just do this simply with extended `glob` features (see [Options which change globbing behavior](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#Options_which_change_globbing_behavior)) provided by `bash`, turn the options on and stash the values to an array. Run it outside the `build/` folder.

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob
fileList=( build/!(*-appstore.ipa) )
```

now loop over the array and do whatever you want to do with it.

```
for file in "${fileList[@]}"; do 
    printf "%s\n" "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create an array of selected files as you can directly iterate them using a glob with brace expansion like this:

```
for file in build/*{-enterprise.ipa,.apk}; do
  echo "$file"
  # app_upload "$file"
done
```